# Why does matplotlib fill_between draw edgelines only on a PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, png

In python's `matplotlib.fill_between` the following minimal working example below draws correctly to the screen, and to the `.png`. In the resulting `.pdf` however, the edge lines are still drawn. How can I fix this?

```
from numpy import *
import pylab as plt

# Sample data
X  = linspace(0,2*pi,1000)
Y0 = sin(X)
Y1 = sin(X+.2)
Y2 = sin(X+.4)

# fill_kwargs (what am I missing?)
fbk = {'lw':0.0, 'edgecolor':None}

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.fill_between(X, 0, Y0 , facecolor = 'b', **fbk)
ax.fill_between(X, Y0, Y1, facecolor = 'g', **fbk)
ax.fill_between(X, Y1, Y2, facecolor = 'r', **fbk)
plt.xlim(pi-.8,pi+.5)
plt.ylim(-.5,.5)

plt.savefig('fA.png')  # No edge lines
plt.savefig('fA.pdf')  # Edge lines!
```

## PNG result

[image]

## PDF result

[image]

While it seems trivial, it becomes *extremely* problematic when you stack 200 `fill_between` plots, all you see is an ugly mess of black!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not perfect, but I've found a solution (and will accept a better one if it comes). [Apparently](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.matplotlib.general/996) postscript might be to blame:

> ... note that interpreting a linewidth of zero as a 1
>   pixel wide line is what PostScript does.  So the only way to
>   get a true zero width for PostScript output is to fill the
>   polygon without stroking it.

The solution is to make the edgecolor the same as the facecolor. This works, but if the facecolor has a transparency it seems that the edgecolor does not get that same transparency value.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty at all, but if you set it to None, it will throw this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, >in draw_wrapper
>      draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1085, >in draw
>      func(*args)
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, > in draw_wrapper
>      draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line > 2110, in draw
>      a.draw(renderer)
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, > in draw_wrapper
>      draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 694, >in draw
>      gc.set_linewidth(self._linewidth)
>   TypeError: a float is required

and continue to render without the line. Stacked violin plots work now with Seaborn!

with 0.0 linewidth:

[image: with 0.0 linewidth]

with None:

[image: Using None]